# How to wrap HTML styling around a paragraph of text

Tags: html

I would like to be able to style a block of text as shown here:

[image]

Specifically:

- It should look just like if I had put all but the last line of the text in one `div` and the bottom line in another `div` and they are styled in the same way
- Padding top and left just like in a `div`
- Same padding to the right of the word "unknown" on line 3 as on word "galley" on line 4
- Same padding below the bottom of all the text of the penultimate line that has no text below it as compared to the padding below the bottom line
- Be able to apply styling to the whole block just like you would with a `div`
- This would be binding to dynamic sections of text with unknown length so hard coding is not an option

If I really had to, I would be willing to accept a solution that looks like this one:

[image]

In that case I'd have to justify the text which isn't my preference

I am looking for a pure html solution if possible, but I'm using Angular & Tailwind in case either of those offer an out of the box solution

EDIT: I am not looking for a red border per se. The red in the images I have added are to show with clear contrast what the element I want would look like on a red webpage.

EDIT 2: `span` in a div, not what I want, see comments:

[image]

Things I have tried

- Mostly searching stack overflow. It's not obvious what to search for, many other results for search terms including "irregular", "border" or "wrap"
- A `div`. Didn't work, obviously.
- `span`. Didn't work either, I don't remember the details of this one
- `text-shadow`, doesn't look like this will work for dynamic text of unknown length
- `mark`. Very close to what I want. Limitations are that it looks like my second choice example, right and left padding only apply to the first and last characters of the text (ruining left justify and right side padding for all the upper lines) and if top & bottom padding are zero, then a red line can be seen between each line of text

Comment: Despite you say that _span Didn't work either, I don't remember the details of this one_  `span` should work as a suboptimal solution, very similar to your second image.  See this pen https://codepen.io/pen/xxQbebb

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to make the pen. Modifying the padding on the container increases the size of the red around the text. (I will edit my question to clarify in case you thought that was part of the goal) Modifying the padding on span itself increases spacing between lines of text and letters. Zero padding also results in red lines between lines of text. Adding a margin doesn't work either. I would like to be able to modify the size of the white area around the text.

Comment: `<div><span>Your text</span></div>` would give that second result with the span has the bg color.

Comment: Thanks for your contribution, that's basically what @PA.'s pen does, see my previous comment. Furthermore using the container styling to give me the padding I want brings this back to being a rectangle which I definitely don't want

Answer (score 2):

If you know the background color and the color is solid, then something like this gets you very close:

```css
.container {
  max-width: 450px;
  padding: 0.5em;
}

p { margin: 0; }

.text-wrapped-container {
  --bg-color: #F00;
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
}

.text-wrapped-bg {
  --padding-inline: 0.5em;
  position: relative;
  overflow: hidden;
  padding-inline: var(--padding-inline);
  padding-block: 0.25em;
  background-color: #FFF;
}

.text-wrapped-bg > span:last-child {
  background-color: var(--bg-color);
  position: absolute;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 2em;
  width: 100%;
  margin-left: var(--padding-inline);
}
```

```html
<div class="container text-wrapped-container">
  <p class="text-wrapped-bg">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.<span></span><p>
</div>
```

The magic is ending the paragraph with that last `<span></span>`.

You can adjust the padding of the paragraph using the `--padding-inline` variable, and it'll translate that as a margin on the span which accomplishes the padding behaviour I *think* you're going for.

**Note**, however, that if the red background is actually a gradient or image, then this strategy does not work. I think for something like that, the solution would either be very tricky, or it's one of the places where HTML's "everything's a box" paradigm falls short.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:
add these declarations to the parent container:

```
.container {
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
justify-content: center;
}
```

Then, instead of using the selector `.sub:not(:last-child)` use:

```
.container:last-child {
align-self: flex-start;
}
```

You can then add padding to `.sub` as you see fit for the look you want.